# How do I avoid shadowing an stdlib module in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-core

I have a program that uses the `Bytes` module from the Ocaml standard library and also opens the `Core_kernel.Std` module at the top of the file

```
open Core_kernel.Std

...

   let let buf = Bytes.make bom_len '\x00' in
```

The problem I am having is that the latest version of Core_kernel introduced a new Bytes module that is shadowing the one from the standard library, which is resulting in a `Unbound value Bytes.make` compilation error.

Is there a way to solve this naming issue without getting rid of the `open` at the top of the file? If I did that it would require changing lots of things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could provide an alternative name for the `Bytes` module as such:

```
module B = Bytes

open Core_kernel.Std

let buf = B.make 10 '\x00'
```

and then do a search-replace in your code to change `Bytes` by `B`.

Another solution would be to avoid using `open`, but this would require a lot of changes in your code, I guess.

Comment: I would rather call it `Stdlib_Bytes` but aside from this, I agree with you.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it solved my problem and works in the general case. However, in the specific Core_kernel shadowing case, Stas's answer will probably be better once that lands in opam.

Answer (score 3):

`Core_kernel` provides `Caml` module that binds everything that is available in standard library.

So, you could write this as

```
open Core_kernel.Std

...

   let buf = Caml.Bytes.make bom_len '\x00' in
```

Unfortunately, `Caml.Bytes` is [added](https://github.com/janestreet/core_kernel/issues/46) only in `113.00.00` version that is not in OPAM yet.